# rails chartkick google charts load times extremely long

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, google-visualization

I am trying to use chartkick to plot some charts with the google charts API. The problem is that the line to set everything up is taking 10-20 seconds to load. Here is the relevant line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
```

Has anyone else had this problem? If so how do you fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why this is, but I managed to get it to go fast by adding http: in the url

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
```

Comment: This didn't really help me... the charts still take a tremendously long time to load.

Answer (score 0):

I generally get around this by grabbing a local copy of the file and only using it in development mode.

```
<% if Rails.env == "development" %>
  <%= #include the local file here %>
<% else %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "http://www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
<% end %>
```

Generally seems ok in production mode.