# chartkick.js Error: Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled - chartkick.js:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am working on upgrading an existing application to the most current versions and stuck on the following error below. I have found some examples here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144640/using-chartkick-in-rails-4-0) | [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693935/rails-chartkick-google-charts-load-times-extremely-long) | [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300885/rails-chartkick-gem-error-loading-chart-no-adapter-found) --- Unfortunately none of these examples work for me.

**Current Error:*

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled - chartkick.js:
  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:5:in '_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__3032669070778132401_2208319440'
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve the chartkick.js?

**application.html.haml**

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title EffortForecast
    = javascript_include_tag "http://www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" 
    = javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" 
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = render 'layouts/login_modal'
    %section
      = render 'layouts/header'
    = content_for :subnav

    %section.container-fluid
      .flash-messages= render 'layouts/flash_messages'
      = yield
```

**application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require_self

Turbolinks.enableProgressBar();
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.8'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '0.18.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]


gem "haml"
gem "omniauth"
gem "omniauth-github"
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2", '~> 0.8.0'
gem "omniauth-openid"
gem "google-api-client"
gem "cancancan"
gem 'bootstrap_form'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'rdiscount', require: 'tilt/rdiscount'
gem 'ruby_identicon'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem "refile", require: "refile/rails"
gem "refile-mini_magick"
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'active_link_to'

gem 'chartkick'
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'faker'
# gem 'skylight'

gem 'bundler', '>= 2.0.0.pre.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'sassc-rails', '>= 2.1.0'
gem "font-awesome-rails"

# bring back removed support for respond_with
# gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'puma'
end

group :development do
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

ruby "2.5.0"
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes I was able to resolve this issue. By removing it from the the file that was using it (app > views > layouts > application.html.haml) Not sure if it was the best option.

Comment: The reason this worked is that you now `//= require chartkick` in your application.js file, instead of including it in your page separately using `javascript_include_tag "chartkick"` (for example)